Service Fabric - EventStoreServiceType and FaultAnalysisService issues
I have a Service Fabric cluster with 5 apps created. All stateless services and nodes are in "OK" health state. Suddenly, there appeared errors for:

fabric:/System/EventStoreService

*'System.FM' reported an error for property 'State'.
Partition is below target replica or instance count.
EventStoreService 5 3 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000009000
-N/P InBuild _nt1vm_0 133730403896161441*

fabric:/System/FaultAnalysisService

'System.FM' reported an error for property 'State'.
Partition is below target replica or instance count.
FaultAnalysisService 5 3 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000005000
-N/P InBuild _nt1vm_1 133730403919308195
I have tried to restart those 2 partition using Restart-ServiceFabricPartition but it seems that this command is obsolete. Then I tried to use Start-ServiceFabricPartitionRestart but it gives a tiomeout. Next, I tried to remove a partition re-create it - also no success. It worked fine for almost a week. What's the reason of this and how can I fix those 2 issues?
I'd be grateful for any hints.
Regards

One of the primary reasons partitions could be below the target replica count is insufficient resources (CPU, memory, or disk) on the nodes. If nodes are under heavy load, the Service Fabric may struggle to allocate the required replicas.

Set up a Service Fabric cluster similar to the one where you're seeing the issue. Ensure it has at least 5 nodes and runs several system services like EventStoreService and FaultAnalysisService.

Create and deploy stateless services across multiple nodes, similar to the production setup. This will check you have the same environment as the production cluster.

Node deactivation:
Start-ServiceFabricNodeTransition -NodeName <NodeName> -NodeInstanceId <InstanceId> -TransitionType Deactivate

Remove Node:
Remove-ServiceFabricNodeState -NodeName <NodeName>

Node Deactivation Logs:
Node Name: _nt1vm_0
Node Instance: 133730403896161441
Health State: Warning
Node is Deactivated.
Event Time: <Timestamp>
Reason: Manual Deactivation (User action)

Service Name: fabric:/System/EventStoreService
Partition ID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000009000
'System.FM' reported that partition is moving to a different node due to node deactivation.
Current Target Replica Count: 5, Available Replicas: 3.
Status: InBuild
Node: _nt1vm_0 (Deactivated)


Try to solve the issue by restarting partitions, rebalancing the cluster, or bringing nodes back online, the logs should start reflecting recovery. Initially, you still see warning states as replicas are reallocated or services are rebuilt. After successful resolution, the logs should indicate recovery.

EventStoreService After Node Reactivation:
EventStoreService has recovered and now has the expected number of replicas (5).
Service Name: fabric:/System/EventStoreService
Partition ID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000009000
'System.FM' reported that partition is building replicas on new nodes.
Health State: OK
Partition reached target replica or instance count.
Expected Replica Set Size: 5, Actual Replica Set Size: 5.
Node: _nt1vm_0
Status: Ready
Event Time: <Timestamp>

FaultAnalysisService After Restart:
FaultAnalysisService partition has also recovered and reached its full replica count after you resolved the issue.
Service Name: fabric:/System/FaultAnalysisService
Partition ID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000005000
'System.FM' reported that partition is healthy.
Health State: OK
Partition is now at the target replica or instance count.
Expected Replica Set Size: 5, Actual Replica Set Size: 5.
Status: Ready
Event Time: <Timestamp>

